# Conditionally checking for element in Cypress.io can't get if conditions working

Tags: cypress

So I'm trying to conditionally check for a popup in a webpage, and close it if it exists. The popup is suppressed if a cookie exists, but the cookie has a guid in the name that I can't get unless it's already been set.

I've tried variations of getting body and struggling with it, using things like the following:

```
cy.get("body").then($body => {
    if ($body.find('[data-id="guide-close-button"]').length) {
      cy.get('[data-id="guide-close-button"]').click();
    } else {
      //you get here if the button DOESN'T EXIST
      assert.isOk('everything','everything is OK');
    }
  })
```

and similar things like this

```
cy.get("body").then($body => {
    if ($body.has('[data-id="guide-close-button"]')) {
      cy.get('[data-id="guide-close-button"]').click();
    } else {
      //you get here if the button DOESN'T EXIST
      assert.isOk('everything','everything is OK');
    }
  })
```

But it either does not assert true if the button does exist, or it gets stuck timing out if the popup has been closed already and fails my test. I know I could technically ignore one error and just get past this but I would like to do it the "right" way, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get this to work how I'm expecting. Any tips on how I can get this to evaluate and close this button if it exists on the page?

Comment: Is it an alert or what kind of popup is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears to be surrounding the redirect, this is right after signing in. Looking at each stage, when I was getting the body it looks like it was still on one of the pages that was still showing signing in. I've added a `cy.url().should('contain','string')` to wait.